# AnyObject to string in swift

Tags: ios, json, core-data, swift, nsarray

I am stuck on this code! I want to remove the optionals what is the best way to do that?
I tried to change the AnyObject in to NSString but I don't know how.

What is the best way to do this?

And my second question is how do I store this in the core data? Is there a cool framework for this?

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlDb)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            println(error)
            //println(json)

            if let contactGroups : AnyObject! = json{
                //println("Contact groepen")
                var contactGroups = contactGroups["contact_groups"] as NSArray

                for cG in contactGroups {
                    println(cG["group_id"]!)
                    //println(cG["contact_id"]!)
                }
            }

            if let contacts : AnyObject = json{
                //println(contacts["contacts"])
                println("Contacten")
                var contacts = contacts["contacts"] as NSArray

                for c in contacts{
                    println(c["id"])
                    println(c["name"])
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the console log

```
 nil
 Optional(1)
 Optional(2)
 Contacten
 Optional(1)
 Optional(Dirk Sierd de Vries)
```

I hope you guys can help me with my school project :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify for loop like below:

```
for c in contacts {
    println(c["id"]  as NSString)
    println(c["name"] as NSString)
}
```

**Explanation:**

In Swift you have to specify object to specific type. If you not than it will by default shows`Optional` keyword. Here your dictionary key values are directly printed on log and you have not specified that which type of value stored in dictionary.

**About Saving in Core Data:**

No there isn't any cool framework which can save data into core data. You need to do it your self. Below link is best to follow to start learning this.

[Swift + Core data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift)

Comment: Now it breaks after the for loop  

nil
Contact groepen
Optional(1)
Optional(2)
Contacten
(lldb)

Comment: Sorry never mind! for the numbers i simply have to use Int! Thanks @Kampai